# Checkbox for group header of extjs grouping grid

Tags: gridview, extjs, grid, grouping, extjs3

I am having a ExtJs `EditorGridPanel` configured with a `GroupingStore`, `GroupingView` and a `CheckboxSelectionModel`.

The Checkbox appears in the grid's header and in all the rows. I want to bring the checkbox on the group header also. My intention is to let the user select all records under a group by selecting the group header's checkbox.

Is there a way to do this? I'm using ExtJs 3.1.1 and [RowActions](http://rowactions.extjs.eu/) plugin from saki.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to acheive this using groupTextTpl config option in groupingView to render a checkbox and using groupClick event of grid to handle the checkbox click event.

more info could be found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?105831-Grid-GroupingView-with-Checkbox&highlight=grid+group+header+checkbox)

Comment: You did not understand the question correctly. None of the examples behind your link uses the grouping feature.